# MvxAutoCompleteTextView stuck at 'Wait starting for '

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross, autocompletetextview

I try to use the MvxAutoCompleteTextView but it's stuck with the following output in Debug :

> mvx:Diagnostic:  3,57 Wait starting for

As soon as I launch my application in the emulator (Android 4.3, Hardware keyboard DISABLED), I see the `Wait starting for` message and as I type, no suggestion is shown.

My ViewModel :

```
public class FirstViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
  public FirstViewModel()
  {
    ClearResults();
  }

  public string[] AutoCompleteSuggestions { get; set; }

  private string _currentTextHint;
  public string CurrentTextHint 
  {
    get { return _currentTextHint; }
    set 
    {
      _currentTextHint = value;
      base.RaisePropertyChanged(() => CurrentTextHint);
      if (CurrentTextHint == null || CurrentTextHint.Length < 3)
        ClearResults();
      else
        BeginSearchAsync();
    }
  }

  private void ClearResults()
  {
    AutoCompleteSuggestions = new string[0];
    base.RaisePropertyChanged(() => AutoCompleteSuggestions);
  }

  private async void BeginSearchAsync()
  {
    await Task.Delay(2000);
    AutoCompleteSuggestions = new string[] { "test", "ok" };
    base.RaisePropertyChanged(() => AutoCompleteSuggestions);
  }

  public string Selected { get; set; }
  public string CurrentText { get; set; }
}
```

FirstView.axml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <MvxAutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/autoCustomerName"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:layout_width="366.7dp"
        android:layout_height="49.1dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:completionThreshold="3"
        android:hint="hint..."
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        local:MvxBind="ItemsSource AutoCompleteSuggestions; PartialText CurrentTextHint; SelectedObject Selected; Text CurrentText;" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: And where do you bind this? Could you describe some more what is actually happening?

Comment: @Cheesebaron There is a link to download the project at the end of my question but I'll add the layout code and a description.

Comment: Sure there is. None one is going to download it as long as it is on an untrusted source and in a archive file. You could have hidden all sorts of nasty surprises in there.

Comment: @Cheesebaron I provided a sample project by courtesy and didn't expected it to make you think that I'm malicious. I'll remove it to dispel your doubts.

Comment: Your intentions are most likely good, however I cannot trust how you are handling security. Something could have been injected into the archive file you provided without your knowledge. I suggest, if you want to share any code, use a repository such as what GitHub or Bitbucket provides.

Comment: @Guillaume I assume you have solved this issue. If not here is my question that ended up answering myself, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26543931/partialtextchanged-stops-firing-on-mvxautocompletetextview-after-item-selection

Comment: @PatLong-MunkiiYebee I think I ended up using another component. That's really tricky... my code seems to do an update per PartialTextUpdate as mentionned in your answer and it still doesn't work. Should it be synchronous ?

Comment: I don't believe it needs to be synchronous. It just means that any update to the PartialText needs to result in a change to the source of the List. It is not always obvious where PartialText is being updated. I pulled the MVVMCross source into my solution so I could put break points in that area of code and watched for what was causing updates

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure your setter for AutoCompleteSuggestions fires it's PropertyChanged event.  I am not sure that this happens when you use the default template for a property.

Secondly, there is an extra step you need to do in your CurrentTextHint property.  Here is a link to one that works.

https://github.com/JimWilcox3/MvxAutoCompleteTest

Comment: that one doesn't work anymore.  Just so you know.  Its a bit broken now.

Comment: It just needed to be updated to the latest MvvmCross Libraries.  Try it now.